# Passing Data Table to stored procedure in HANA accepting table type as input using ADO.NET for HANA API

Tags: c#, ado.net, hana

I am developing a C# application, where I am accessing a stored procedure in SAP HANA. The stored procedure has an input parameter of type 'Table Type'. Now, to pass parameter as table type from my application to database, I tried creating a datatable object in my code and passing it to database. But it looks like SAP HANA for ADO.NET Client API does not support passing table type/datatable type parameters to stored procedure. I tried the following work-around as suggested in some blogs :

1. Created a local temporary table
2. Filled it from client
3. Sent it to database using `WriteToServer()` method
4. Sent a reference to it while calling the stored procedure

I want to verify whether this approach is fine or whether any alternative exists.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach is correct. You can create Table Type in SQL and pass the data table as a SQLParameter in to the stored procedure.

Comment: Sadly this approach doesn't seem to work with HANA. I have to create a local temporary table and send a reference to it.